# Separating client and server in docker-compose not working

Tags: node.js, docker, server, docker-compose, client

Basically, the front end is a react application. The back end is a normal express server.

```
client
 ┣ public
 ┣ src
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┣ package.json
 ┗ yarn.lock
server
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┣ index.js
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┗ package.json
┣ .dockerignore
┣ .env
┣ .gitignore
┣ docker-compose.yml
```

client/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install 

COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

server/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install 

COPY . .
CMD ["nodemon", "index.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./client/

    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:./app # when you edit local, reflect change in container

  server:
    build: ./server


    ports:

      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:./app   # when you edit local, reflect change in container
```

when I run the compose by `docker-compose up --build`, tons of errors...................................................

in the client-side sh: react-scripts: not found

in the server-side sh: nodemon: not found

Comment: I assume `react-scripts` and `nodemon` are added as dependencies? (and if they are added as `devDependencies`, that you're not running Node in production mode)

Comment: when I exec -it containerID bash,    node_modules are there

Comment: Yes, `node_modules/` is there, but does it contain the right packages? You need `nodemon` in your (dev)dependencies. And if they're in your dev dependencies, you need to make sure NPM/Node isn't running in production (which makes it ignores devDependencies). I don't know what mode that Docker image runs in.

Comment: Your `volumes:` declaration is telling Docker to ignore the `node_modules` directory that gets `npm install`ed in the image build and to use an arbitrarily old version of it from a previous run instead.  You should delete these blocks.  Since the content of the image is fixed, you also don't need `nodemon` here.

Comment: Why is your `/app/node_modules` folders volumes?